# Bigquery, pull the first day of the month for a date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that returns the first day of the month based on a date column to use for monthly aggregation.  I am not sure how to do this in BigQuery's syntax.

For instance: `'2015-02-26'` would return as `'2015-02-01'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
Depends on taste and mood

The one that is regexp based is below for you to try

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(d, r'(\d{4}-\d{2})-\d{2}') + '-01' AS first_day
FROM 
  (SELECT '2015-02-26' AS d)
```